# Exclude path from SSLVerifyClient require

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, jira, ca

I have Apache 2.4.18 (Ubuntu) running as a reverse proxy. To protect my personal environment, I have added a `SSLVerifyClient require` and so far no problems.

However, Jira wants to access itself to load some languages strings. According to the logging of Jira it's `https://{DOMAIN_URL}/rest/gadgets/1.0/g/messagebundle/nl_NL/gadget.common%2Cgadget.project` where `gadget.common%2Cgadget.project` can be different, depending on which module it wants some translation string.

Ok, fine. So to solve this solution, I thought of making this URL available to Jira and therefor skip SSLVerifyClient for only this specific URL.

My current config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName {DOMAIN}
    Redirect permanent / https://{DOMAIN}
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin info@{DOMAIN}
        ServerName {DOMAIN}

        <Location / >
            Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Location>

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

        SSLEngine       on
        SSLCompression      Off
        SSLProtocol         ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder     On
        SSLCipherSuite      EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLCertificateFile  {SSL}/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   {SSL}/privkey.pem

        SSLCACertificateFile    {PATH}/ca.crt
        SSLVerifyClient     require
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck  on
        SSLVerifyDepth      1

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPass / http://localhost/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

I tried to add the following two snippets after `SSLVerifyDepth     1`

```
<Directory "/rest/gadgets">
    SSLVerifyClient      none
</Directory>
```

And

```
<Location /rest/gadgets>
        SSLVerifyClient none
</Location>
```

I did however check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html (Client Authentication and Access Control), however both are not working. I'm not quite sure, but I perhaps the specified path in `Location` and `Directory` is not the right one. I wanted to make it universal and just check if the first part of the URL contains `/rest/gadgets`.

I hope my question is somewhat clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is an answer to my question:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName {DOMAIN}
    Redirect permanent / https://{DOMAIN}
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin info@{DOMAIN}
        ServerName {DOMAIN}

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

        SSLEngine       on
        SSLCompression      Off
        SSLProtocol         ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder     On
        SSLCipherSuite      EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
            SSLCertificateFile  {SSL}/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile   {SSL}/privkey.pem

        SSLCACertificateFile    {PATH}/ca.crt
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck  on

        <Location / >
            SSLVerifyClient     require 
            SSLVerifyDepth      1

            Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Location>     

        <Location /rest/gadgets>
                SSLVerifyClient none
        </Location>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPass / http://localhost/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

The trick was to extend the current `Location` and move `SSLVerifyClient`. Afterwards add an extra `Location`-directive with the excluded path, `rest/gadgets` in this case.